# How to convert ScalaFX root to image and then save it in local

Tags: scala, javafx, scalafx

I am creating a "line chart" using scalaFX as below and want to save the scene as an image in the local.

I know there is one function in scalaFX - snapshot but I do not know how to use it. I could not find any examples anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple example (based upon the *ScalaFX* [*Catagory Line Chart Demo*](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/blob/master/scalafx-demos/src/main/scala/scalafx/scene/chart/CategoryLineChartDemo.scala)) that you should be able to adapt to your requirements:

```scala
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils
import scalafx.geometry.Side
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.scene.{Node, Scene}
import scalafx.scene.chart.{CategoryAxis, LineChart, NumberAxis, XYChart}

object TakeSnapshot
extends JFXApp {

  val dataPairs = Seq(
    ("Alpha", 50),
    ("Beta", 80),
    ("RC1", 90),
    ("RC2", 30),
    ("1.0", 122),
    ("1.1", 10),
  )

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title.value = "Take a Snapshot"
    width = 640
    height = 400
    scene = new Scene {
      root = new LineChart(CategoryAxis("X Axis"), NumberAxis("Y Axis")) {
        title = "LineChart with Category Axis"
        legendSide = Side.Right
        data = XYChart.Series[String, Number](
          "Series 1",
          ObservableBuffer(dataPairs.map {case (x, y) => XYChart.Data[String, Number](x, y)})
        )
      }
    }
  }

  // Take the snapshot.
  takeSnapshot(stage.scene.root(), new File("MyLineChart.png"))

  // Take a snapshot of the specified node, writing it into the specified file. The dimensions of
  // the image will match the size of the node (and its child nodes) on the screen in pixels.
  def takeSnapshot(node: Node, file: File) {

    // Take the snapshot, which returns a WritableImage instance.
    //
    // Note:
    // 1. The first argument is a SnapshotParameters instance. If null, it will use the associated
    //    scene's settings. More here:
    //    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SnapshotParameters.html
    // 2. The second argument is a WritableImage instance. If null, it will creat a new
    //    WritableImage instance, with the dimensions of the associated node, will be created.
    //    More here:
    //    https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html
    //
    // Scala frowns on the use of null values, but there's really no alternative here.
    val image = node.snapshot(null, null)

    // Convert the image to a buffered image. Passing null for the BufferedImage instance argument
    // will ensure one is created for you.
    val bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null)
    assert(bufferedImage ne null)

    // Now write the buffered image into a file (in Portable Network Graphics, PNG, format.)
    // This may throw an exception if the file isn't writable, etc.
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file)
  }
}
```

After running the program, you should find a file called "MyLineChart.png" in your project's root directory.

Further *JavaFX* documentation for `snapshot()` is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-).